How do I remove the target wasm32-wasi and add the new wasm32-wasip1
When I try to rustup update, I get
error: component 'rust-std' for target 'wasm32-wasi' is unavailable for download for channel 'nightly'
error: Sometimes not all components are available in any    given nightly. If you don't need the component, you could try a minimal installation with:
error: 
error:     rustup toolchain add nightly --profile minimal
error: 
error: If you require these components, please install and use the latest successful build version,
error: which you can find at <https://rust-lang.github.io/rustup-components-history>.
error: 
error: After determining the correct date, install it with a command such as:
error: 
error:     rustup toolchain install nightly-2018-12-27
error: 
error: Then you can use the toolchain with commands such as:
error: 
error:     cargo +nightly-2018-12-27 build

A quick search shows a blog on this. Basically wasm32-wasi is no longer available on nightly as of 2024-10-17. According to that we should be using wasm32-wasip1.

These commands worked for me,
rustup target remove wasm32-wasi
rustup update
rustup target add wasm32-wasip1

